# binding template content to an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs, observable

I have a CRUD page and I want it to be updated in every operation made.

So I tried to use Observable and all the CRUD functions works fine (just Add and Delete for now) but i need to refresh the page to see the changes.

I tried to call `this.ngOnInit()` function in the end of every operation function but nothing worked.

**productmanagement.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { routerTransition } from '../../../router.animations';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Category } from 'src/app/_models';
import { CategoryService } from './_services/category.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-productmanagement',
    templateUrl: './productmanagement.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./productmanagement.component.scss'],
    animations: [routerTransition()],
    providers: [CategoryService]
})
export class ProductManagementComponent implements OnInit {

    public categorysObservable$: Observable<Category>;

    constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.categorysObservable$ = this.categoryService.getAll();
    }

    categoryAdded(categoryname: string) {
        this.categoryService.add(categoryname);

    }

    deleteCategory(category: any) {
        this.categoryService.delete(category.idCategory);
    }
}
```

**category.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
    public categorysRequest: Observable<Category>;
    public categorySubject: Subject<Category>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.categorySubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
    }

    getAll(refresh: boolean = false) {
        if (refresh || !this.categorysRequest) {
            this.categorysRequest = this.http.get<Category>(`http://localhost:5000/api/Category`);

            this.categorysRequest.subscribe(
                result => this.categorySubject.next(result),
                err => this.categorySubject.error(err)
              );
        }
        return this.categorySubject.asObservable();
    }

    getById(id: number) {
         return this.http.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/Category/` + id);
    }

    add(category: string) {
        return this.http.post<Category>('http://localhost:5000/api/Category', {Category: category}).subscribe();
    }

    update(category: Category) {
        return this.http.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/Category/` + category.idCategory, category);
    }

    delete(id: number) {
        return this.http.delete<any>(`http://localhost:5000/api/Category?id=` + id).subscribe();
    }
}
```

**productmanagement.component.html**

```
<!--Categorys-->
    <div *ngIf="(categorysObservable$ | async)">
        <div *ngFor="let category of (categorysObservable$ | async)">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p style="display: inline" name='idCategory'> {{ category.category1 }} </p>

                    <button class='btn btn-danger' style="float: right;" (click)="deleteCategory(category)">delete</button>
                    <button class='btn btn-warning' style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">add Product</button>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="category.product.length>0 else noProduct">
                    <table class="card-body table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Reference</th>
                                <th>Serial Number</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>quantity</th>
                                <th style="width: 165px"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody *ngFor="let prod of category.product">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ prod.product1 }}</td>
                                <td>{{ prod.reference }}</td>
                                <td>{{ prod.serialNumber }}</td>
                                <td>{{ prod.price }}</td>
                                <td>{{ prod.quantite }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class='btn btn-outline-warning'>edit</button> &nbsp;
                                    <button class='btn btn-outline-danger'>delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <ng-template #noProduct class="align-content-center">
                    <br>
                    <p class='text-center'>No Poducts yet</p>
                </ng-template>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Including `this.ngOnInit()` in the component didn't help also using the `AsyncPipe` in the template. So I and thik that the solution is by binding the Observable withe the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are way too complicating things. You don't need to create another Observable if "http's" `get()` will return an Observable in itself. If you want to unsubscribe from the subscription, you can do it when your component destroys. If I understand it correct, then the only pointy of adding the `if()` block in `getAll()` is not to call another HTTP request if one is already on the way.

Make your `getAll()` as:

```
getAll() {
    this.http.get<Category>(`http://localhost:5000/api/Category`);
}
```

Make a class variable in your component which holds the subscription

```
getAllSubscription: Subscription
```

Make a `getAllCategories()` method in your component.

No need of `categorysObservable$` prop in the class, instead of this make a `categories` prop which hold the actual data.

```
getAllCategories() {
  if (this.getAllSubscription) {
    this.getAllSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  this.getAllSubscription = this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
    this.categories = data;
  }, (error) => {
      // errors will come here
  })
}
```

Remove `async` pipe from your template and use this instead

```
<div *ngIf="categories">
    ....
</div>
```

Modify other methods in your service to just return an Observable(don't subscribe there), for example:

```
add(category: string) {
    return this.http.post<Category>('http://localhost:5000/api/Category', {Category: category});
}
```

call `getAllCategories()` on your `categoryAdded()` and `deleteCategory()` methods

```
categoryAdded(categoryname: string) {
    this.categoryService.add(categoryname).subscribe((data) => {
       // do something with data, show error success msgs,etc
       this.getAllCategories();
    })
}
```

**Note:** There could be other ways (using `rxjs` flattening operators) to achieve a `getAll()` in update(), delete() Observables itself. I have used them as separate Observable believing you would need separate success/error responses from each of the requests.

**Update**

If you have to use flattening operators, you can implement it this way.

```
add(category: string) {
    return this.http.post<Category>('http://localhost:5000/api/Category', {Category: category}).pipe(
      mergeMap((dataFromAdd) => {
        // can just return this.getAll() if you don't care for the response of the above post() request. (But you should care!)
        return this.getAll().pipe(
          map((dataFromGetAll) => {
                return {
                  addResponse: dataFromAdd,
                  allCategories: dataFromGetAll
                }
            })
          )

      })
    )
}
```

In your component, modify `categoryAdded()` as

```
categoryAdded(categoryname: string) {
    this.categoryService.add(categoryname).subscribe((data) => {
       this.categories = data.allCategories
    })
}
```

Comment: This method worked well but can you include the flattening operators way to achieve a `getAll()` ?